# Is there a way to extract nodes that connect roads in OSM data?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, nodes

Is there a way to extract only the nodes that connect links in OSM data?  I am trying to locate US Interstate exit and entrance ramp ends in order to compare with my data.  I've been able to extract end nodes but a lot of the ramps (motorway links) are a continuous line or single feature with only two ends connecting to the motorway while ignoring the secondary road.  It seems that OSM data doesn't have shared nodes but instead stacks them at connection points.  I'm going to look into extracting those but I am hoping there will be a more thorough way that will give me node attribute information if it's available.

Example is the highlighted motorway link below

[image]

EDIT:

I'm specifically looking for start and end node location of highway exit ramps (motorway_link) for all of US and Canada with the ability to differentiate between both start and end node.  Here's an example of the nodes I need.

[image]

Comment: In that case, the OSM representation is that there is no connection point (maybe one on  the right hand side at the bottom) - in logic terms it could just be an overpass / underpass without connection. Clearly the physical situation isn't like that, but it'll be guesswork to identify these situations if there is no node. Tagging might help a bit, but it probably won't be reliable.

Comment: There *are* shared nodes in OSM. A connection between two ways is defined as a node shared by *both* ways. Read [OSM elements](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Elements) and [OSM XML](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_XML) or just fire up an OSM editor and take a look at the actual data.

Comment: @BradHards There are nodes at the intersection it's just that they are stacked on top of each other not shared.  (The black dots are direction arrows)  Maybe that's more of an artifact of Qgis or shapefiles.

Comment: The nodes **are** actually shared in the OSM database, but any conversion to shapefile or other GIS formats converts them to line vertices that have the same coordinates.

Comment: @scai I wasn't suggesting that there aren't shared nodes, but that sometime the ways just overlap.

Comment: @brink: Did you get shapefiles instead of PBF?

Comment: @BradHards  Yes, shapefiles but as suggested by AndreJ they do get converted.  I'll try looking around in the pbf file.  The answer below, however, looks to be the most promising.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try Overpass API to identify nodes where both highway=motorway and highway=motorway_link ways intersect. Here's an example:

```
[bbox:{{bbox}}];

way[highway=motorway];node(w)->.a;
way[highway=motorway_link];node(w)->.b;
node.a.b;
out;
```

Try it in overpass turbo! http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/qDZ

Comment: I assume the asker wanted the connection of the links with other road types. The connection with the motorway should always be start or end of a link.

Comment: @AndreJ: you're probably right, http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/qE1 should get those intersections of motorway_link with non motorway/motorway_link ways. Could be adjusted as needed to also return the motorway_link again. Let's wait for the OP's feedback.

Comment: @mmd I am focusing on only exit ramps not entrance. The first query works perfect for getting the start of the exit ramp but the second one brings up both exit and entrance connections to other road types. Is it possible to write a query that only pulls data for exit ramps?  Two separate queries might be the best way since I need to differentiate between start and end nodes when comparing with my data.

Comment: I'm having a bit of a hard time to figure exactly what you're trying to achieve. What kind of data do you need for exit ramps? Preferably, can you add some example of actual osm data (way ids)? The following query will return the  motorway_junction node, along with the first bit of the motorway_link: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/qHC - if data is tagged correctly in OSM, that should in fact return exit ramps.

Comment: @mmd That query is close. I need the start and end node of exit ramps only for the US and Canada, with the ability to differentiate between the two.

Comment: @mmd I added an example to my original question.  I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. I think the following query is as close as we can get: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/qJs - it tries to identify all motorway_link segments based on a motorway_junction node, and returns both that junction node, as well as the end node (i.e. the first node where we intersect some non-motorway road). In the XML response you will also find a "start" marker and an "end" marker to tell them two apart. This could also be done for each exit node on its own: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/qJt

Comment: @mmd I'm getting an error on both queries having to do with this line. (complete( node(w); way(bn)[highway=motorway_link];););  I can post an image of the error if it will help.

Comment: Right, this kind of query needs some features which are not yet released, unfortunately. Will post an updated query with a link to a test server soon

Comment: Updated links: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/qLV and http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/qLW - they point to a test server. Once version 0.7.55 comes out you can turn to the previous links above again.